# Анимация прямоугольника

Tags: wpf, xaml, анимация

Как передвинуть прямоугольник по нажатию кнопки?
пробовал такой XAML код,но получаю InvalidOperationException:

Не удается разрешить все ссылки на свойства в пути свойств "Canvas.Top". Проверьте, что соответствующие объекты поддерживают такие свойства.

```
     <Canvas>
    <Rectangle Canvas.Top="200" Name="redRectangle" Canvas.Left="200"  Fill="Red" Stroke="Blue" MinHeight="50" MinWidth="50"></Rectangle>
    <Button  Canvas.Top="250" Canvas.Left="10" >move left
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="redRectangle" From="200" To="50" Duration="0:0:5"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Canvas.Top">
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
```

Это должен быть правильный синтаксис для attached property.

Comment: ,Действительно,проблема была именно в этом.переписал код-все получилось.Большое спасибо!

Comment: @david_I: Пожалуйста!